# Web Service returning a null dataset occasionally

Tags: web-services, ado.net, dataset

I am having the most frustrating problem, basically I have a website and a webservice running on the same server. Both use ADO.net to connect to data tables using a couple of custom calls I have created myself, the website has never had a problem with connecting to a particular proc to return data, however the webservice, once in say every 100 calls to that proc, returns an empty dataset even though it should have come back populated and does in a query in SQL Mgmt Studio. The weird thing is it works most times, but on the odd occasion returns this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0. at System.Data.DataTableCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)

```
 Dim SQLCmd As SqlCommand = CreateSPCommand("VerifyCredentialsSP")
 SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Credentials.Password)
GetData(SQLCmd)
ds.DataSetName = "Customer"

    If ds.Tables(0) IsNot Nothing Then

        ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Customer"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to catch the exception being thrown, but the better method is to check for `null` or `nothing` in your case.

Do not access the index `ds.Tables(0)...`.
Do a check if your dataset `ds` is `null` before accessing it like so:

```
If ds IsNot Nothing then
  'only then can you index ds.
end if
```

In this way you avoid a lookup on the index of your dataset given that it contains some valid reference.  In your method you are accessing `Tables(0)` which may or may not exist, without a valid check your code could potentially throw an exception, and in this case it has!

Comment: Hi JonH, I agree, but the problem is it should still return a table even though there are no rows returned. Its like the webservice/data connection drops out somehow but only once every 100-150 calls.

Comment: David that I cannot tell you why, but you should still put in the error checking.  The result of it not pulling the data from the table, you will have to either use profiler or some other tool to understand why it isn't coming back.  It could be just a timing issue..those issues are very hard to resolve, good luck either way.